# Is there a way in increase Bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I would like to increase the award amount of the bounty that I set a few days ago.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe that this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can only let the bounty expire -- or flag it for a mod to remove it under *extreme circumstances only* -- and then start a new one.